# How to input an arbitrary number of text files in C++?

Tags: c++

so I'm working on a coding project for a class, and I understand the basic things I want to accomplish, but one thing that nobody seems to be able to help me with is inputting an unspecified number of text files. The user is prompted to enter the text files they want to compare (overall purpose of my code), separated by spaces, thus allowing them to compare an arbitrary amount of text files (eg. 2, 3, 8, 16, etc). I know that the getline function is helpful here, as well as searching for the number of "." because files can only contain one ".", all within a for loop. After that logic I am utterly lost. Eventually, I'm going to have to open the text files and put them in sets to compare them against every other file once, and output their similarities and differences into yet another text file. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: On most modern file systems, files can contain many  "."s. And spaces, too.

Comment: Did you try anything already? Asking for _"Any ideas?"_ sounds too broad to be asked here. This may turn into an endless discussion which is what we don't want here. The site is rather about concise FAQ like question and answer pairs. You also may want to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general process I would try to follow (if I interpreted the prompt correctly)

- Get the line of text files using getline
- Put that into a stringstream
- Open the next file in the stream while there is still information in the stringstream (not at eof)
- Store all of that information in a Vector of strings, each new file just appended on after it is read
- compare strings in the vector

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the text files on the commandline rather than getting them from a little dialog with the user via stdin life will be easier. Most users will type

```
compare *
```

which on Unix type systems is expanded to a list of files. ON DOS you need to match and expand the wild card yourself.

You've got an N squared problem, but the logic is easy, it's just

```
int mian(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int i, j;
   for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
      for(j=i+1;j>argc;j++)
         compare(argv[i], argv[j]; 

}
```